# Wierd behaviour in eager load Laravel/Lumen 5

Tags: laravel, eager-loading, lumen

I have a query.

```
 $item = Item::with('relationship')->get();
```

That works fine.  It eager loads the related item.
Now on that relationship item, I have another relationship.

```
 function you_like(){
     return $this->hasOne('App\Like','item_id')->where('liker_id',Auth::user()->id);
 }
```

That works fine.  When I do this, it works and I can access that like.

```
 dd((boolean)$item->relationship->you_like)
```

Displays exactly what I want it to display.  True, if liked.  False if not.
However....because I have a large list of items, I wanted to eager load whether I like them or not. Like so.

```
 $item = Item::with('relationship','relationship.you_like')->get();
```

And tried this too

```
 $item = Item::with('relationship')->with('relationship.you_like')->get();
```

Now when I dd((boolean)$item->relationship->you_like) it returns null/false, even when it should be true.

What gives here??
Does it have something to do with using the Auth::user() class inside the relationship?  Thats what my intuition tells me.

Comment: You can do : ```$item = Item::with('relationship.you_like')->get();``` ? Although if all you want is to know whether they liked it or not (bool), you should do : ```$item->relationship()->you_like()->count() > 0```.

Comment: Thats not my problem.  The relationship works.  The issue is that when I eager load it, it doesnt.  I can do $item->relationship->you_like and it works.  But if I do with('relationship.you_like'), then try to do $item->relationship->you_like, it doesnt work